# chromatic class of graphs of order $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, chromatic-polynomial

Let $\mathcal{G}(n)$ be the isomorphism class of simple graphs of order $n$. We say two graphs in $\mathcal{G}(n)$ are chromatic equivalent if their chromatic polynomials have an equal linear coefficient.  The resulting equivalence classes $\chi(n)$ under this relation are called the chromatic class of order $n$.

I have the following questions :

1. What is the cardinality of $\chi(n)$?
2. What are some references to study about $\chi(n)$?

For small numbers, the cardinality of $\chi(n)$ is equal to 1,1,2,5,12,37,121, . . . 
But except for a first few terms, it is not matching with any sequence in OEIS.

Thank you.

Comment: Why the linear coefficient?

Comment: Linear coefficient counts many interesting objects related to the graph, for example, see the introduction of https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06382. I am interested in the combinatorics of the linear coefficient.

Comment: Have you calculated the cardinality for a few values of $n$?

Comment: Yes, I have. Please check the question. I have just added these details.

Comment: Maybe you also could provide the numbers for connected graphs?

Comment: @MartinRubey for any disconnected the value will be zero. So we can get the data from connected graphs by subtracting one.

Comment: I believe this value is also the last entry of the $h$-vector of the cographic matroid dual to the graphic matroid of $G$ (see Merino, "The Chip Firing Game and Matroid
Complexes"). Questions about which values can arise in certain positions of $f$/$h$/$g$ vectors of various classes of complexes can be really hard...

Comment: The connection to matroids also suggests that maybe rather than group graphs by number of vertices, it could make sense to group them by number of edges.

Comment: @SamHopkins, according to Merino, the h-vector of this matroid is just the evaluation of the Tutte polynomial at $y=1$, and, for connected graphs, the coefficient is the evaluation of the Tutte polynomial at $x=1, y=0$ (taking into account duality).  (cf https://www.findstat.org/St000948)

Comment: @MartinRubey: I think what I said is correct. By duality, the $h$-vector of the *co*graphic matroid is the evaluation of the Tutte polynomial of the graph at $x=1$. The evaluation $x=1$, $y=0$ of a Tutte polynomial of a matroid is called the $\beta$-invariant of the matroid (this name is due to Crapo). Certainly, the $h$-vector of the cographic matroid enumerates $G$-parking functions by degree: this is how Merino resolved Stanley's $h$-vector conjecture for cographic matroids. Hence the last component of the $h$-vector should enumerate maximal $G$-parking functions.

Comment: Btw, don't know what the issue is, but findstat links still take an extraordinarily long time to load on my browser.

Comment: @SamHopkins: sorry, I did not mean at all to say that anything you said was incorrect.  Concerning FindStat, yes, it is still broken, and I have still not figured out why.